# Convert a complex data dictionary into dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the below dictionary:

```
 {
   'process':{
      'state':'running',
      'username':'abc',
      'ppid':624,
      'cpu':{
         'total':{
            'pct':0.0
         },
         'start_time':'2019-03-14'
      },
      'cmdline':'acde',
      'pgid':0,
      'name':'xct',
      'memory':{
         'size':3608576,
         'rss':{
            'bytes':28897280,
            'pct':0.0008
         },
         'share':0
      },
      'pid':696
   }
}
```

Would expect to see:

```
state   username    ppid    pct start_time  cmdline pgid    name    size    bytes   pct share   pid
running abc 624 0   03/14/2019  acde    0   xct 3608576 28897280    0.0008  0   696
```

please notice, Ive ignored these:

```
  process
   cpu
    total
   rss
```

because they are data dictionaries (where I am getting the values from, so I don't care and can be ignored)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an automatic way to do this, but this seems to work:

This method 'flatten's the dictionary (extracting all inner dictionaries)

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    flat = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if (isinstance(v,dict)):
            flat.extend(flatten_dict(v))
        else:
            flat.append((k,v))
    return flat
```

Then you can use this to generate a series (from a `dict`) and transpose that into the dataframe you show in your OP:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series({a:b for a,b in flatten_dict(data)})).transpose()
```

(where `data` is your original nested dictionary)

The output I got:

```
state   username    ppid    pct start_time  cmdline pgid    name    size    bytes   share   pid
0   running abc 624 0.0008  2019-03-14  acde    0   xct 3608576 28897280    0   696
```

Notice that `pct` appears twice, and that causes one of them to overwrite the other one - you could overcome this by not converting the final output of the method (a list of tuple) into a dictionary - your short post is not specific enough to understand exactly what you want at this level of detail.

Please let me know if something is not clear or if it is not working as expected.